# Distribution of multivariate polynomial evaluation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, probability-distributions, random-functions

Let $R:\mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^m$ be a multivariate quadratic map. Here $\mathbb{F}$ denotes the finite field of order $q$.

I am curious to know whether the  distribution of $R(x)$ for uniform $x\in \mathbb{F}^n$
is computationally indistinguishable from uniform.

I was reading a paper and authors assumed this fact. I am attaching the screenshot for your kind reference.  Refer to Theorem 2.

Link to the paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/131.pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJdFq.jpg)

Comment: Certainly it is not true for *all* quadratic maps (consider $\mathbb{F}$ with 3 elements, $n=m=1$ and $R: x \mapsto x^2$), so I guess the question is *when* you can assume it to be computationally indistinguishable. This Crypto SE question might help: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53382/whats-a-quadratic-map-and-how-do-i-invert-it